# adding more data in highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

the follow code shows to add data, which is working.

```
           $(".test").change(function() {
               var value = this.getAttribute("value");

               if (value == 'a') 
               {
                   chart.series[0].setData([100, 200, 300, 400, 100, 200]);
               }

               else if (value == 'b') 
                {
                   chart.series[0].setData([100, 500, 300, 100, 100, 200]);
               }

               else if (value == 'c') 
                {
                   chart.series[0].setData([100, 300, 400, 200, 200, 100]);
               }

                else {
                   alert("Error!");
               }

           });
```

this is using radio buttons, now what if for value a you want 2 sets of data, and also a diffrent name for yaxis.

is that possible?

i no to add title for yaxis is with the following code:

```
           yAxis: {
               title: {
                   text: 'data'
               }
```

but how will you put this into the code above..

i have the title working, now to add another set of data, would it be like this

```
        chart.addSeries({
             data: [194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4]
        });
```

the 2nd set of data is showing but keeps adding it every time i click the radio button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to set the axis title using the setTitle() method

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.setTitle()

```
chart.yAxis[0].setTitle({text:"data"});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cw5cZ/

Comment: how will this fit into the code, can you please add it so i can see where it goes. this is the code:

                
          chart.yAxis[0].setTitle({
            text: 'New Y axis title'

Comment: No problem. Try the jsfiddle I posted and click the button.

Comment: can you look at the code again, am trying to add data and trying to use your method..

Comment: You didn't post enough of your chart code to be sure, but if the second series isn't defined yet, you may need to call chart.addSeries. http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.addSeries()

Comment: i have used this:

            chart.addSeries({
                data: [194.1, 95.6, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4]
            });
        
but it just keeps adding everything i click the radio button, when i just want it to add the once